# SweetJS : Write a macro for a specific library

Tags: macros, sweet.js, ramda.js

I'm currently working on a little project which consists about writing macros for Ramda. Here is an example :

```
let map = macro {
    rule { $f $array } => { R.map($f, $array) }
    rule { $f } => { R.map($f) }
}
```

I tried to compile this simple sample of code as a beginning :

```
var R = require('ramda');

function log (value) {
    console.log(value);
}

map log [1, 2, 3];
```

Because of hygiene, the compiled code looks like this :

```
var R$759 = require('ramda');
function log$761(value$762) {
    console.log(value$762);
}                   
R.map(log$761)[1, 2, 3];
```

My problem is that I don't know how to make reference to ramda.

Has anyone tried to write macros for a specific library and encountered this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment the ways to do it are a little hacky. In the next release when we get ES6 modules this will actually be taken care of automatically for you but until then the best option is to have an initialization macro (this is what [ki](http://ki-lang.org/) and [contracts.js](http://www.contractsjs.org/) do). This works by having a shared variable in scope for all of your macros and then having the user first invoke an `import` macro that does the necessary `require`:

```
var r_lib;
macro import {
    rule { $name from $path } => { 
        r_lib = require($path);
    }
}
let map = macro {
    rule { $f $l } => { r_lib.map($f, $l) }
}

import R from "ramda"

map log [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked very well ! Do you know when the next release is planned ? I should keep an eye on github repo anyway :)

Comment: I keep saying it's releasing soon and one of these times I'll be right :)